Remove title bar for non-GTK apps
Is there a way to manually edit, smth like, a .css file to remove the title bar for non-GTK based apps? Or to copy the default Adwaita theme and edit it to use it as a user theme?
I'm using GNOME 46.6 and the title bar on apps like VScode, Krita, Wine lauched apps, etc. seem redundant (just have the title and close button) and occupy too much screen space. I tried GNOME extensions but they where buggy. Any recommendations are much appreciated.

I doubt it, because Mutter is entirely CSD-based. Perhaps if you were using KWin.

@RokeJulianLockhart Ok, thanks for the insight!

If I'm right, https://superuser.com/questions/1850632/how-to-force-dwm-to-render-server-side-decoration-ssd-on-all-windows/1863156#1863156 might be informative in this context. Apologies I couldn't give an answer. As an example, you would probably want to set Mutter's DConf equivalent to KWin's noborderrule= to whatever value corresponds to force off irrespective of window class.
